# Обьединение двух запросов MySQL

Tags: запрос, mysql

Как выбрать в таблице все строчки по дате самой последней добавленной в таблицу строки?
Пока додумался только до такого неработающего кода.

```
$max_date = mysql_query("SELECT max(date) date FROM example ORDER BY date DESC");
$article = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE date='$max_date'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY `date` DESC");
```

Comment: плюс

    WHERE `date` = MAX(`date`)

Comment: @Fike, я сначала подумал что нужно абсолютно все выбрать с таблицы, оказывается нужно с максимальной датой =)